# Core Data add object to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I am trying to implement Core Data to-many relationship with two entities - WardrobeList and Items. 
WardrobeList has a to-many relationship "items", so that one can add multiple items to a wardrobe.

I have created NSManagedObject subclasses. Here are how they look.

WardrobeList.h

```
@class Item;

@interface WardrobeList : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BabyDetails *babydetails;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *items;

@end

@interface WardrobeList (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)removeItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)addItem:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeItem:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Item.h

```
@class WardrobeList;

@interface Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * brand;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * buydate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * giftby;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * product;
@property (nonatomic, retain) WardrobeList *wardrobe;

@end
```

I have a table view controller called WardrobeList where I display the list of wardrobes. I have an Add button here, which takes me to the Add Item view controller where user populates details for an item.

I pass the selected wardrobe object through a segue. Here is the code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddItem"]) {
        //Assign managed objects to dest view controller
        AddItemViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.wardrobe = wardrobe;
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowItems"]) {
        ItemsList *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.wardrobe = wardrobe;
    }
}
```

In AddItemVC.m, I capture all details input by user and add them to a new Item Managed Object. I then try to add this Item object to the wardrobe that I have received from the segue, in my save button method.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new item object
        Item *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        if (!product) {
            newItem.category = category;
            product = [products objectAtIndex:[self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
            newItem.product = product;
        }

        //Saving the text fields
        newItem.name = self.itemTextField.text;
        newItem.brand = self.brandTextField.text;
        newItem.age = self.ageTextField.text;
        newItem.color = self.colorTextField.text;
        newItem.quantity = @([self.quantityTextField.text intValue]);
        newItem.price = @([self.priceTextField.text floatValue]);

        //Save date
        newItem.buydate = self.datePicker.date;

        //Save image
        newItem.image = imageData;

        //Save description
        newItem.desc = self.descTextField.text;

        //Save the gift field values
        if (self.giftTextField.text) {
            newItem.giftby = self.giftTextField.text;
        }

        //Manage the relation between wardrobe and item
        *[self.wardrobe addItemObject:newItem];*
        newItem.wardrobe = self.wardrobe;
        NSLog(@"Item saved");
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I receive this error message when save method is executed.

```
[WardrobeList addItemObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x788d2880
```

Can someone please guide me as to what I am doing wrong here and how this can rectified?

Eventually I would like to show all the Items in a selected wardrobe in a new table view, once a user selects a particular wardrobe in WardrobeList.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors` auto-generated or typed? If I have relations i.e.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *rooms;`

my code is generated with the item name and not the Entity name

`- (void)addRoomsObject:(Room *)value;`

(recognize the s in Rooms). If it's not this, take a look at your model (correct connection between the 2 entities, same naming in model and class) or look if there are more error-information

Comment: My CoreDataGeneratedAccessors are typed as I added the to-many relationship after I had generated the subclass. I will update my subclass with the additional 's' and try running it again. I'll keep you posted, thanks!

Comment: I was able to save the item after adding the 's' to my CoreDataGeneratedAccessors. Didn't realize something this trivial could cause a problem. Appreciate your help!